# Bad encoding of imported data from MS Access into MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssms

I have mdb file with MS Access database. When I try to import data into MSSQL database using Taks -> Import data with Microsoft Jet Database Engine as input driver and Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server as output driver, I have problem with special characters like Č, Ř etc.

"GE Medical Systems ČR" => "GE Medical Systems ÈR" for instance.

Is there any way how to setup encoding for input? Or any solution for my old slavic language?

Comment: My two cents: Export from Access, instead of importing from MS SQL or the migration assistant. Access understands its own encoding, getting other programs to do so can be a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting database to Access2003 may fix the import problem.
Install MSACCESS2003 open DB and go to menu -> Tools-> Database management -> Convert database -> access 2002-2003 and save as new file.
Import via DTS to mssql now keeps such characters.